# How to access duplicate values in simple combo box in ExtJs

Tags: java, gwt, extjs, combobox, gxt

I have a SimpleComboBox in GUI which contains some duplicate items also. Assume there are 3 items which is same as "domain". When i select second "domain" or third "domain", the selected item and selected index is always pointing to first occurance of "domain". How can i correct, so that the selected index/item is right one, instead of first occurance of item?

ComboBox with duplicate values:

[image: ComboBox with duplicate values]

When i select "domain" at fourth occurence it will always pointing the first occurance of "domain".

Output:

[image]

When i select the "192.168.1.30" at last occurenece, it will point the first occurance of "192.168.1.30".

Please any one help me.

```
private SimpleComboBox<String> domainName = new SimpleComboBox<String>();
domainName = WidgetUtil.getStringCombo("Domain Name", 12, true, domainNameList, null);
        domainName.addSelectionChangedListener(getReportSelectionListener());
        domainName.setForceSelection(true);
        domainName.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL);
 private Button New, add, remove;
 New = WidgetUtil.getButton("New", "new", "");
    New.addSelectionListener(buttonAction());
    thirdLayoutContainer.add(New);
    add = WidgetUtil.getButton("Add", "add", "");
    add.addSelectionListener(buttonAction());
    add.setStyleAttribute("paddingTop", "10px");
    thirdLayoutContainer.add(add, formData);
    remove = WidgetUtil.getButton("Remove", "remove", "");
    remove.addSelectionListener(buttonAction());

 public void componentSelected(ButtonEvent ce){
            String domain_name = null;
            if (ce.getComponent().getId().equals("remove")){
                System.err.println("Clicked remove button...");
                domain_name = domainName.getRawValue();
                domainNameList.remove(domain_name);
                systemDetailsMap.remove(domain_name);
                systemDetailsMap.remove(domain_name + "_USER_NAME");
                systemDetailsMap.remove(domain_name + "_HOST_NAME");
                systemDetailsMap.remove(domain_name + "_PASSWORD");
                domainName.removeAll();
                domainName.add(domainNameList);
                userName.clear();
                hostName.clear();
                password.clear();
                System.err.println("After remove domain name list ---> " + domainNameList);
                System.err.println("After remove map ---> " + systemDetailsMap);
            } else if (ce.getComponent().getId().equals("add")) {
                System.err.println("Clicked add button...");
                domain_name = domainName.getRawValue();
                domainNameList.add(domain_name);
                systemDetailsMap.put(domain_name, domain_name);
                systemDetailsMap.put(domain_name + "_HOST_NAME", hostName.getValue());
                systemDetailsMap.put(domain_name + "_USER_NAME", userName.getValue());
                systemDetailsMap.put(domain_name + "_PASSWORD", password.getValue());
 //                 domainName.clear();
                domainName.add(domainNameList);
 //                 domainName.reset();
                System.err.println("After add domain name list ---> " + domainNameList);
                System.err.println("After add map ---> " + systemDetailsMap);
            } else if (ce.getComponent().getId().equals("new")) {
                System.err.println("Clicked new button...");
                userName.clear();
                hostName.clear();
                password.clear();
                domainName.removeAllListeners();
                domainName.removeAll();
                domainName.clear();
                domainName.setEmptyText("Add a new domain");
                userName.setEmptyText("Add a new username");
                hostName.setEmptyText("Add a new hostname");
                password.setEmptyText("Add a new password");
                domainName.addSelectionChangedListener(getReportSelectionListener());
            }
        }
        };


 private SelectionChangedListener<SimpleComboValue<String>> getReportSelectionListener(){
    SelectionChangedListener<SimpleComboValue<String>> ReportListener = new SelectionChangedListener<SimpleComboValue<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent<SimpleComboValue<String>> se) {
            SimpleComboValue<String> selectedValue = se.getSelectedItem();
            String value = selectedValue.getValue();
            System.err.println("Selected Value ---> " + selectedValue.getValue());
            if (value != null && !value.equals("---New---") ){
                userName.clear();
                hostName.clear();
                password.clear();
                userName.setValue(systemDetailsMap.get(value + "_USER_NAME").toString());
                hostName.setValue(systemDetailsMap.get(value + "_HOST_NAME").toString());
                password.setValue(systemDetailsMap.get(value + "_PASSWORD").toString());
            } 
        }
    };
    return ReportListener;
}
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not using Ext-gwt just the standard ext-js, but I think I know what you need! You should define a display and value field.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    store: xyz,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

You just have to make sure, that the duplicated items are getting unique id. I think that if this is possible in ext-js it should also be possible in ext-gwt!